# searching in special custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with my search page result. I already create search theme.
when I search word 'موفقیت' which it is already in my data base it return all result and works fine but I just want to search in special custom post type not all of post and pages.how can I fix this problem

here is my code

```
    <?php 
 get_header(); ?>
<div class="title-pack col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <span class="line visible-sm-block"></span>
        <span class="visible-sm-block tittle-style">نتایج جستجوی شما</span>
    </div>
<div id="search-results" class="wrapper" role="search">


<!-- COUNT RESULTS -->
<div class="results">
    <?php
    /* Search Count */
    $allsearch = &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1"); 
    $key = wp_specialchars($s, 1);
    $count = $allsearch->post_count; 
    _e('');
    _e('"<span class="search-terms">');
    echo $key;
    _e('</span>"'); 
    echo $count . ' مورد یافت شد';
    wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div>
<!-- / COUNT RESULTS -->

<?php if ($allsearch->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($allsearch->have_posts()) : $allsearch->the_post(); ?>

<!-- LIST RESULTS -->
<section>   
    <h3>
        <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to 
        <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> - 
        <span class="search-time"><?php the_time('F, j, Y') ?></span>
        </li>
    </h3>
</section>
<!-- / LIST RESULTS -->

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<!-- 404 SEARCH -->
<div class="404-search">
<?php _e("Oops... We couldn't find what you were searching for. Please try again"); ?>
</div>
<!-- / 404 SEARCH -->

<?php endif; ?>

     </div>


 <div style="clear:both;"></div>            
 <?php get_footer(); ?> 


     <div style="clear:both;"></div>            
     <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

any idea would be appropriated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$allsearch = &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1");
```

with this:

```
$allsearch = &new WP_Query( array( 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    's' => $s,
    'post_type' => 'YOUR-POST-TYPE-NAME',
    ));
```

> Replace `YOUR-POST-TYPE-NAME` with your `custom post type` name

Comment: can I ask you what is this line said ?`s=$s&showposts=-1`?? I always use wp_query as you wrote but I mix up with that line

Comment: its a query string, `$s` is the keyword you search `showposts=-1` means to return all results, its for pagination purpose, you can limit number of posts, by it, say `showposts=6` will return at most 6 such posts at a time, `'posts_per_page' => -1` is the same thing

Comment: pleasure is all ours @mimi

Answer (score 0):

WP_Query can be used for searching a custom post type too

Just replace these

```
 &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1")
```

with

```
 &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1&post_type=your_post_type_name")
```

Replace `your_post_type_name` with your custom post type name